# Angular-6- HTTPClient post request success but returns error?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 6, i am using HTTPClient to post my image data to REST endpoint. Endpoint uploads pic and returns uploaded image url successfully but at client side, in console there is error thrown as follows:
[image]

When i see in network tab at console, there is no error in response i get image url.Following is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';


const URL = 'http://localhost:8082/uploadPic';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  imgUrl:String=null;
  selectedFile: File;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  }

  onUpload() {
     this.uploadToCloud();
  }

  uploadToCloud(){
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('file', this.selectedFile);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/uploadPic', uploadData).subscribe(event => {
        console.log('Event:',event); // handle event here
      });
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me to get successful response.

Comment: You don't handle the error. Are you asking how to make the request valid? The code looks okay, it just seems like the server is responding with an error for some reason

Comment: By default Angular 6 HttpClient expect all responses to be JSON formatted unless you specify not to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{responseType: 'text'}` to deal with non-json responses. You can read more here:
https://angular.io/guide/http

Also you can return a JSON like object as response which would be the most recommendable way to solve your problem

Comment: thanks , it worked for me.